# setState is delayed by one state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, setstate

Don't know what I am doing wrong here, maybe it is a rookie mistake.

I am trying to recreate chess.

My state is delayed by one.. i.e. when I click on square to show possible moves of piece, the possible moves will appear but only after my second click, they will show on the right spot. And for the 3rd click the state from 2nd click will appear on the right spot and so on.
What am I doing wrong here?
I am sending few code examples from my **next.js** app.

This is my **Square** component

```js
export default function Square({
  x,
  y,
  color,
  content,
  contentClr,
  handleClick,
}) {
  const col = color == 'light' ? '#F3D9DC' : '#744253';

  return (
    <div
      className='square'
      x={x}
      y={y}
      style={{ backgroundColor: col }}
      onClick={() => handleClick(x, y)}
    >
      {content != '' && (
        <h1 style={{ color: contentClr == 'light' ? 'white' : 'black' }}>
          {content}
        </h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my **Board** component

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Square from './square';

import styles from '../styles/Board.module.css';
import rookMoves from './possibleMoves/rookMoves';

export default function Board({ initialBoard, lightTurn, toggleTurn }) {
  let size = 8;
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(initialBoard);
  const [possibleMoves, setPossibleMoves] = useState([]);
  //possibleMoves .. each possible move is represented as x, y coordinates.

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('board state changed');
  }, [board]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('possible moves state changed');
    console.log(possibleMoves);
    renderPossibleMoves();
  }, [possibleMoves]);

  const playerClickOnPiece = (x, y) => {
    let pos = getPossibleMoves(x, y, rookMoves, [left, right, up, down]);
    setPossibleMoves(pos);
  };

  //where to is object that has functions for directions in it
  const getPossibleMoves = (x, y, movePiece, whereTo) => {
    let posMoves = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < whereTo.length; i++) {
      posMoves = posMoves.concat(movePiece(board, x, y, whereTo[i]));
    }

    console.log(posMoves);
    return posMoves;
  };

  const renderPossibleMoves = () => {
    console.log('board from renderPossibleMoves ', board);
    let newBoard = board;
    for (let i = 0; i < possibleMoves.length; i++) {
      newBoard[possibleMoves[i].y][possibleMoves[i].x] = 10;
    }
    setBoard(newBoard);
  };

  const squareColor = (x, y) => {
    return (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0) || (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 1)
      ? 'light'
      : 'dark';
  };

  const handleClick = (x, y) => {
    if (lightTurn && board[y][x] > 0) {
      console.log(
        `show me possible moves of light ${board[y][x]} on ${x} ${y}`
      );
      playerClickOnPiece(x, y);
    } else if (!lightTurn && board[y][x] < 0) {
      console.log(`show me possible moves of dark ${board[y][x]} on ${x} ${y}`);
      playerClickOnPiece(x, y);
    } else if (board[y][x] == 'Pm') {
      playerMove();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='board'>
        {board.map((row, y) => {
          return (
            <div className='row' key={y}>
              {row.map((square, x) => {
                return (
                  <Square
                    x={x}
                    y={y}
                    key={x}
                    color={squareColor(x, y)}
                    content={square}
                    contentClr={square > 0 ? 'light' : 'dark'}
                    handleClick={handleClick}
                    playerMove={toggleTurn}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Board from './board';

let initialBoard = [
  [-4, -3, -2, -5, -6, -2, -3, -4],
  [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4],
];

export default function Game() {
  const [lightTurn, setLightTurn] = useState(true);

  const toggleTurn = () => {
    setLightTurn(!lightTurn);
  };

  return (
    <Board
      initialBoard={initialBoard}
      lightTurn={lightTurn}
      toggleTurn={toggleTurn}
    />
  );
}
```

I am sending an example that shows only possible moves with rook but if u click on any light piece.

Comment: In `renderPossibleMoves` you're mutating the `board` array that's in state, which React won't pick up. Try cloning the state array with `let newBoard = [...board];` before modifying and updating the state.

Comment: Oh, u are right! somehow I thought that js will create local copy of it as normal, but I am not passing it to the function, rather getting it as global var.. My bad there! thank u very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@juliomalves`'s comment helped!
I was mutating state directly in renderPossibleMoves. Spread operator solved the issue.

from

```js
let newBoard = board;
```

to

```js
let newBoard = [...board];
```